# openMPI Master Node Setup Configuration

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing, openmpi

I'm trying to setup a relatively small cluster (36 cores) with openMPI and I've run into a small problem. I have all the openMPI libraries and any dependencies installed and running correctly (I can run a hello world MPI program on each computer as the localhost). The problem is that I can't seem to find too much documentation on how to get the computers to execute a program together. I can do the mpirun --hostfile command but I don't want to have to specify the host file every time I execute a job. Plus, future users won't have access to all the IP addresses on the cluster all the time. They and I expect to be able execute mpirun -np 20 programFile with no problem. Can someone provide some guidance on what I need to do from this point? To be fair, I've only taken one class in college where we wrote parallel programs with MPI, but they never showed us how to SETUP a new cluster with openMPI. I appreciate any advice you guys can give. I've found this guide through my searches [MPICH_Cluster_Setup](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MpichCluster) which would be great if it was openMPI. Is there a similar guide out there that pertains to openMPI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a cluster scheduler like Torque, SLURM, or SGE (all are free/FOSS). These lets users reserve nodes for their use, and all "talk" to open MPI to tell it what nodes to use for that users job (so that they don't have to use a hostfile).

Per the MPICH cluster setup doc, it's just about exactly what you need for open MPI, but there's no need to setup MPD at the end (MPICH has since deprecated MPD, anyway).